# Spark Debug specific Task

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I know it's an general question but I still found it necessary.

I have a spark job with 1 stage and 64 tasks. each task took on average 1.5 minute. I am using HDP 2.5 with yarn.
my DAG is :

```
hadoopRdd -> Filter -> map
```

I wanted to drill down into a specific task and understand why it was so slow (stage info is shown).
I mean which part of the DAG took a lot of time so I can tune my properties.
where can I found that info (timelines) ? should I set my log4j to print the time also in order to see that? do I have any component on spark UI that can help me with that?